# задание про масссивы в java

Tags: java, массивы

```html
Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] A = new int[20];
int[] B = new int[20];

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    A[i] = 0;
    B[i] = 0;
}

System.out.println("enter small let");
char Small = in.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("enter big let");
char Big = in.next().charAt(0);

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int sum = A[i] + Big;
    int sum2 = B[i] + Small;
    A[i] = A[i] + sum;
    B[i] = B[i] + sum2;
    if(A[i] > B[i])
        System.out.println("the sum of the large letters is greater than the small ones, so print out the large ones " +A[i]);
```

задание-Напишите программу, которая принимает массив символов (char) размером 20. Программа выведет Big, если общее количество заглавных букв больше, чем общее количество строчных букв.

Программа напечатает «Маленький», если общее количество строчных букв больше, чем общее количество прописных букв.

Программа выведет “the sum of the large letters is greater than the small ones, so print out the large ones»
Можете показать пожалуйста или исправить ошибки я не могу понять почему не работает

Comment: Последний абзац вопроса непонятен. Код делает вообще что попало. Введите одну строку, никаких маленьких или больших запрашивать не нужно. Потом посчитайте, сколько каких.

Comment: @vlua, То есть вы когда смотрите на свой(?) код, не видите, что он не соответствует заданию?  Для начала, где массивы `char`, почему вместо них используются массивы `int`?  Зачем их обнулять отдельным циклом, если массивы примитивов и так будут содержать нули (в отличие от С/С++)?  В чём смысл считывать из ввода _по одному_ символу?  Какой смысл действий в основном цикле?